# Meaning of "绽开来" in 这句话让她脸上的皱纹菊花般绽开来?

Tags: translation, meaning-in-context

> 她的话音刚落,一直在旁边默默无语的老公说道:“我们就是后一种。”这句话让她脸上的皱纹菊花般绽开来。"

Just after she spoke, her husband who'd been staying in silence beside her said, "We're the latter kind." This remark made the wrinkles on her face...?

Mmm, I really couldn't understand this. Does it mean open/smoothen? If that's the case, why's is said to be "like chrysanthemum?"

Comment: A simple google translate suggest 绽开 -> bloom.

Comment: @tsh I know, that was why I'm asking. "Wrinkles blooming" doesn't make any sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

这句话 -- these words

让她脸上的皱纹 -- make the wrinkles on her face

如菊花(**绽放**)般 --  like chrysanthemum (**bloom**)

**绽放**开来-- bloomed open

> 这句话让她脸上的皱纹如菊花(**绽放**)般, (**绽放**)开来
>
> These words made the  wrinkles on her face (bloomed) like chrysanthemum (bloom)

"绽放" (bloom) here is a poetic description, -- put a mental image in readers' mind, metaphorically compare "put on a big smile" with "chrysanthemum blooming"

Answer (score 2):

绽, [绽放](http://www.youdao.com/w/eng/%E7%BB%BD%E6%94%BE/#keyfrom=dict2.index), means *bloom/blossom*.

皱纹菊花般绽开来 means *the wrinkles bloom like chrysanthemum*, which is used to describe *smile* here.

---

<sup>To be honest, using 绽放 instead sounds more natural to me.</sup>

Comment: Is it a poetic phrase commonly used by the Chinese? I mean using "wrinkles blooming like chrysanthemum" to describe smiling? Honestly, I can't get the relation between blooming wrinkles and smiling...

Comment: @Fai91 I don't think it's commonly used, it might need much more imagining? About the process of blooming and the smile of an old woman with wrinkles on her face.